# How does one query a DateTimeOffset column to get all rows for a particular day?

Tags: t-sql

So let's say you have a table with the column below (type is datetimeoffset(3)).

```
    DTO_Created
    2017-04-28 03:16:56.942 -05:00
    2017-05-01 00:20:54.925 -05:00
    2017-05-01 12:17:52.752 -05:00
    2017-05-01 23:21:00.198 -05:00
    2017-05-02 01:19:23.254 -05:00
```

How would you query to only get the rows created on 2017-05-01? (3 rows total)  I am attempting this, but am not getting all 3.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE DTO_Created >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND DTO_Created <= '2017-05-01 23:59:59.999'
```

The problem seems to be caused by the type (datetimeoffset) because this doesn't happen with regular datetime columns.

---

Environment: SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `datetimeoffset` for the `where` clause as well.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    DTO_Created DateTimeOffset
)

INSERT INTO @T(DTO_Created) VALUES
('2017-04-28 03:16:56.942 -05:00'),
('2017-05-01 00:20:54.925 -05:00'),
('2017-05-01 12:17:52.752 -05:00'),
('2017-05-01 23:21:00.198 -05:00'),
('2017-05-02 01:19:23.254 -05:00')
```

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T 
WHERE DTO_Created >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 -05:00'
AND DTO_Created < '2017-05-02 00:00:00.000 -05:00'
```

Results:

```
DTO_Created
2017-05-01 00:20:54.925 -05:00
2017-05-01 12:17:52.752 -05:00
2017-05-01 23:21:00.198 -05:00
```

Another option for 2016 or higher version is to use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but you'll have to add the hours difference to the search value, and beware of daylight savings time:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T 
WHERE DTO_Created >= CAST('2017-05-01 05:00:00' AS DateTime2) AT TIME ZONE 'Easter Island Standard Time' -- -05:00
AND  DTO_Created < CAST('2017-05-02 05:00:00' AS DateTime2) AT TIME ZONE 'Easter Island Standard Time'
```

If you want to ignore local time and treat the UTC part of the `DateTimeOffset` as if it was `DateTime` you can simply cast the `DateTimeOffset` to `Date`, though that would be a non-[sargable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE CAST(DTO_Created As Date) = '2017-05-01'
```

Comment: In order to use either of these methods to query, it looks like I would have to know the offset for the time period (-5 or -6 depending on whether daylight savings time is in effect or not) and include this offset in my query.  Is there a way around this?  It seems like this would make the creation of dynamic queries very difficult.  For example, if I want to query for some dates in February, I would have to know whether or not daylight savings time is in effect or not, and include it in the query.

Comment: The Datetimeoffset is stored as utc + offset - meaning that `2017-05-01 00:20:54.925 -05:00` is actually `2017-04-30 19:20:54.925` translated to local time.

Comment: Is there some way to tell SQL Server "I only want to query local time" and then I wouldn't have to include the offset in the query? Depending on the date in the year, I would have to feed in different offsets (again, due to daylight savings time) and know which offset to feed in depending on which date.  If I could just query without offset, and have SQL Server understand that this means I just want to query against what I can see in the table, that is what I would like to do.  Hopefully this makes sense.  My queries will be created dynamically and adding in logic to create offset is tough.

Comment: If you want to treat the datetimeoffset as local datetime then your original query is ok since `2017-05-01 00:20:54.925 -05:00` is actually before `2017-05-01` in local datetime. If you want to ignore the offset and treat the UTC part as a datetime you can use the query in the other answer (though it's non-sargable).

Comment: Thanks, but the other answer results in this error: "The style 109 is not supported for conversions from datetimeoffset to datetime."  Basically, if the row has '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000 -05:00' in this column, I just want to be able to query the '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' part of it and ignore the offset.  I want to be able to query this column in the same way that I would query a column like datetime.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a query to treat the UTC part as `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, DTO_Created, 1) >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND CONVERT(DATETIME, DTO_Created, 1) <= '2017-05-01 23:59:59.999'
```

OR this

```
cast(DTO_Created as datetime) >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND cast(DTO_Created as datetime) <= '2017-05-01 23:59:59.999'
```

Comment: This gives this error: "The style 109 is not supported for conversions from datetimeoffset to datetime."

Comment: I've edited my answer it should not return an error now